# Error shown when generating models in RoR, wrong number of arguments in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, arguments, associations

I'm new in RoR. I'm learning models and generating the models for my app and it's associations. The console generated the error when I tried:

$ rails console

> mypath.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.3/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1395:in
>   `has_many': wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3)
>   (ArgumentError)

and more lines of errors but this one is the key I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I was writing on the same line different associations which is not correct:

Wrong:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :questions, :answers, :comments, :votes
end
```

Correct:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers
  has_many :comments
  has_many :votes

end
```